# Process builder creates an Opportunity record but the values of the three dependent picklist fields are not set

Tags: process-builder, dependent-picklist

**Use Case:**

When  a check box on the Account record is set to True , Create a new Opportunity Record, and set the values of the dependent picklist fields.

**What Works so far, and what doesn't ?**

The process builder successfully creates an opportunity record but the values of the three picklist fields are not set.

Please note that these picklist fields are Dependent picklists. basically 2 levels of dependencies

e.g Povider is dependent on Product_Type__c, and
ProductType__c is dependent on Product__c

[image]

Comment: Please enable the debug logs and check if any other code/process is overriding these values during opportunity creation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, not sure what was wrong, but I deleted the process, and recreated it.